# Different installations of Python on web server - NTLK installation issue

Tags: python, django, nltk, virtualenv

I am new to web development. I am having an issue importing nltk in Python when I access my shared web hosting account (Linux) with Putty.

I have a shared hosting account and I have several domains. I have started trying to develop a couple of site using Django: let's call them Site1 and Site2. I have separate virtualenvs for Site1 and Site2.

I have in the shared "base" directory an installation of Python3.6.

I then have separate installations of Python in the virtualenv bin folders for site1 and site2.

I am trying to install NLTK on Site1. I have done the following:
(1) Accessed the server through Putty.
(2) Run the virtualenv for Site1.
(3) Typed `pip install nltk`. 
- The package is saved to the `/site1-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages` directory. I presume the PIP command is linked to the Python installation for Site1.
(4) To download the NLTK Data, I run the Python shell by typing `python` in the Site1 virtualenv. When I type `import nltk` in the python shell, I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1,
 in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'
```

I think this is because the 'python' command is running the installation of Python in the base directory of the shared hosting account; and not the installation of Python in the virtualenv for Site1.

How do I fix this issue? I realise I am probably making several bad decisions.

Comment: When you say you are 'typing python in the virtualenv' do you mean you are activating the virtual env? e.g. in cmd line you are typing something like "virtualenv\Scripts\activate".

Comment: After I have activated the virtualenv, i then run the Python shell